# Elastic beanstalk fails after deleting load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Apologies for the rushed question but I've been getting stressed about this. I am running an elastic beanstalk application on the free tier. After I had two many instances running I ended up being charged. While talking to a support member about costs it was recommened I delete my extra load balancing groups. Only having one, I went and deleted it but now the app is failing. I tried creating a new load balancer but the problem persists.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a "load balancing **group**"? It sounds like you just deleted your load balancer, so now there is nowhere for your site's traffic to go to. You will probably need to rebuild your beanstalk environment to get everything working correctly again.

Perhaps what the support individual was trying to suggest was that you recreate your application as a single-server non-load balanced application. That would require you to change some settings and recreate your app environment though. You can't just delete the load balancer in a load balanced environment and expect Amazon to know how to route your traffic afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Was up late freaking about it, hence the poor question. I will have to rebuild it I suppose. Is it possible to use a snapshot of a database ina  new build and have the same data in it, do you know?